# Command line parsing using key values in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I m using Argparser in Python to parse the command line arguments. Here is my code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('input', type=str)
parser.add_argument('method', type=str)
parser.add_argument('output', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

If I specify `python argparser.py input.txt hello_world output.txt`, it works fine. I want to support something like, `python argparser.py -i input.txt -m hello_world -o output.txt` and `python argparser.py --input input.txt --method hello_world --output output.txt`

I tried this, `parser.add_argument('-i', 'input', type=str)` but this does not seem to work. It keeps throwing error. How can I fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code(it is fully working on my side):

```
import argparse

def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input", type=str, help="input file")
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--method", type=str, help="message")
    parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", type=str, help="output file")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args

arguments = parse_args()

print(arguments)
print(arguments.input)
print(arguments.method)
print(arguments.output)
```

**Usage example:** python3 parse.py -i some

**Result:**
Namespace(i='some', m=None, o=None)

Comment: This works if i specify `python filename.py -i input.txt -m hello_world -o output.txt`. This does not work if i specify `python filename.py --input input.txt --method hello_world --output output.txt`. I want to support both of these.

Comment: It works on both cases: `'code`ppikh@ppikh:~$ python3 parse.py -i input.txt -m hello_world -o output.txt
Namespace(input='input.txt', method='hello_world', output='output.txt')
input.txt
hello_world
output.txt
ppikh@ppikh:~$ 
ppikh@ppikh:~$ python3 parse.py --input input.txt --method hello_world --output output.txt
Namespace(input='input.txt', method='hello_world', output='output.txt')
input.txt
hello_world
output.txt
ppikh@ppikh:~$ 
`code`

Comment: Try only my code save in file and try to run this file using command: python3 parse.py --input input.txt --method hello_world --output output.txt  where parse.py - filename

Comment: Ah my bad, i m too sorry, it was all a '-' that i missed. thanks.

Comment: No problem :) I happy to help you.

Comment: FYI: `type=str` is redundant.  The default type is always `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
 parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', help='Input')
```

You can check out the different options in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

EDIT: I never tried with -i=input but the option without using **=** works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i','--input', type=str)
parser.add_argument('-m','--method', type=str)
parser.add_argument('-o','--output', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
```